# Can I append a single branch of rdf:List rdf:rest's with one SPARQL Update query using VALUES keyword?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am trying append to an rdf:List in SPARQL like so:

```sql
DELETE {
  ?end rdf:rest rdf:nil .
}
INSERT {
  ?end rdf:rest _:b0 .
  _:b0 rdf:type rdf:List .
  _:b0 rdf:first _:b1 .
  _:b1 rdfs:label ?t .
  _:b0 rdf:rest rdf:nil .
}
WHERE
  { <http://example/~/blah> (rdf:rest)* ?end .
    ?end  rdf:rest  rdf:nil
    VALUES ?t { "txt1" "txt2" "txt3" "txt4" }
  }
```

but I get the txtX's appended as rdf:rest's all at once which makes four branches, when what I'd like is to have the update executed sequentially for each value, to make a single branch.  Is there a way to do this with a single query or a variable length string of VALUES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with a single SPARQL query. The `WHERE` part allows for pattern matching, but not for recursion per each value of the `VALUE` clause.